# How to use both FutureBuilder and setState method?(Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I tried to load data from the database by using FutureBuilder like this code.

```
// counter application

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SetStateScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SetStateScreenState createState() => _SetStateScreenState();
}

class _SetStateScreenState extends State<SetStateScreen> {
  Future<int> getData() async {
    int initNumFromDB = 0; // fetch some asynchronous initial value
    return initNumFromDB;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int counter;
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
            Widget childWidget;
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              counter = snapshot.data; 
              childWidget = Center(
                child: Container(
                    child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      counter += 1;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("$counter"),
                )),
              );
            } else {
              childWidget = Container();
            }
            return childWidget;
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

But, when pushing the button and running the setState method, FutureBuilder loads initial data again and reset the counter number. How to load initial data once, and run this code correctly?

Comment: **initState() {  getData();  }** you need to call getData from initState

Comment: I think the async method in the initState method is not good because it starts running the build method before the async method is completed.

Comment: True but after once complete the async you can use set state and in this case, it will call only once

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you Kumbhani:)

Comment: IT Solve your issue or not?

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. It solve my issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this is the proper way to use

```
class SetStateScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SetStateScreenState createState() => _SetStateScreenState();
}

class _SetStateScreenState extends State<SetStateScreen> {
    Future<int> getData() async {
        int initNumFromDB = 0; // fetch some asynchronous initial value
        return initNumFromDB;
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        getData(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call you future method inside the initstate method . As such it will run only once when the widget is built and not everytime when setstate() is called.

Comment: For this, you can use the comment feature no need to post the comment as an answer.

Comment: In this way, how to initialize values by asynchronous way?